# Multiple using of Android media Player

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I am using Android MediaPlayer to play video files. And I also have another media player which is able to play videos that are not supported by default Android MediaPlayer. I have two SurfaceView each for its MediaPlayer. And I need to hide-show them when a user switches from one player to another. When user switches from default Android MediaPlayer i need to hide default SurfaceView and stop player.  When user switches back to default Android MediaPlayer i need to re-create SurfaceView and MediaPlayer. For the first creation of SurfaceView and MediaPlayer everything is OK. But in the second time I have only black screen without video. May be this is because of wrong stop of default MediaPlayer? Thanks
This is function where i stop default media player.

```
private void stopMedia() {
   mPlayer.stop();
   mPlayer.reset();
   mSurfaceView.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
}
```

This is function where I create MediaPlayer and surfaceView

```
public void createPlayer() {
   mDefPlayer = new DefaultVideoPlayer(mainActivity, this);
   mDefaultSurfaceHolder = mDefaultSurface.getHolder();
   mDefaultSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mDefaultCallback);
}
```

This is SurfaceView callback

```
mDefPlayer.setUpVideoFrom(path);
mDefPlayer.setDisplay(mDefaultSurface, holder);
mDefPlayer.setSeekBar(mSeekbar, mTime, mLength);
mDefPlayer.play();
```

And i start to play video in onPrepared()

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mPlayer.start();
}
```